# how to use a string variable with sprintf C++ / opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, printf

I want to use sprintf function to insert a char variable as file name as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>


char fileNameImage[1000];  // a string, containing the name of the JPG file
char fileNameGraph[1000];  // a string, the name of the graph JPG file

time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer [80];

time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
strftime (buffer,80,"%I:%M:%S.%p-%x",timeinfo);

sprintf( fileNameImage, "%s.jpg",buffer ); // i need help here
sprintf( fileNameGraph, "%s-graph.jpg",buffer); // i need help here


        imwrite( fileNameImage,frame );
        flip(graph,graph,0);  // flip it vertically before saving as JPG
        imwrite( fileNameGraph,graph );
        flip(graph,graph,0);  // flip it back
        file1 = fopen("Passed_objects.html","a");  // "a" is append (add at the end)
        // printf to a text file
        fprintf( file1, "<img src = %s><img src = %s>"
                "Threshold = %d, countObjects = %d <br>\n",
                fileNameImage, fileNameGraph, threshold, countObjects);
        fclose(file1);
    }
```

i am using this C++ code along with opencv to save a captured frame in .jpg format giving the current system time as its name. But it doesnt work.It doesnt save anything.

but instead of that two lines if i replace ,

```
sprintf( fileNameImage, "%06d.jpg", countObjects);
sprintf( fileNameGraph, "%06d-graph.jpg", countObjects);
```

its works and saves the frame. (countobjects is the int variable which increments in each loop).

My question in brief is to add the time instead of int varible.

In the code which i provided is not the whole code... its an extract

Comment: here is not even one object related to opencv....

Comment: Your description is also ambiguous, since C++ supports a number of distinct things that may each be described as a "string".   What are you referring to as a "string variable"?

Comment: Print out buffer independently. Does it contain any character which are illegal in file names?

Comment: Apologies if i make the question unclear.And want to mention i am new to coding.
I have a loop running through to count the passing objects if the mean  
of ROI is higher than the threshold.If its higher it counts one object and keep running ( countobjects ++ )

In each case the an object is detected i want to take that frame and save it giving the system time/date as its name.
But this only works when i put 

sprintf( fileNameImage, "%06d.jpg", countObjects);
sprintf( fileNameGraph, "%06d-graph.jpg", countObjects);

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean i want to assign the buffer to fileNameImage and fileNamegraph.

Comment: Note that use of `%x` in the format of `strftime` will often result in something like `07/05/17` resulting in `imwrite` trying to save to a non-existent directory.

Comment: @G.M. i removed that i tried... but problem stays the same.

Comment: Even having removed `%x` you still need to ensure `buffer` doesn't contain any characters that might be interpreted as "special" by the file system.  Please do as suggested by @MalcolmMcLean and print out the contents of `buffer` after it's been initialized with `strftime` (also note that you really should be checking the return value from `strftime`).

Comment: @G.M can u tell me how to do it ? i didnt understand what it meant by printing it out .

Comment: `printf("\n*** buffer is [%s] ***\n", buffer);` immediately after the call to `strftime`.

Comment: but if i print that out like that... it will print on command prompt, and still i dont have any clue to use it as my file name using imwrite.

Answer (score -1):

**fileNameImage:**
05:43:08.PM-05/07/17.jpg
**fileNameGraph:**
05:43:08.PM-05/07/17-graph.jpg

Comment: How does this answer the question?